# How to dynamically provide function argument defaults from config files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, inspect

How to have argument defaults dynamically set by a configuration file created by the user?

The configuration file consists of function paths with their arguments declared. Being able to import the function will allow me to get the function name and its module path.

Does anyone have any idea how to import a function given the number of a line inside the function and the python file containing the function (including functions inside classes)?

---

EDIT (Added the below use case as requested by the comments)

I want to retrieve the function that defaults its argument to `configured_arg()` in the examples below:

```python3
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(kwarg=configured_arg()):
        ...

def some_function(kwarg=configured_arg()):
    ...

    def another_function(kwarg=configured_arg()):
        ...

def configured_arg():
    # NOTE: `inspect.stack` returns the caller as "<module>"
    # NOTE: `inspect.stack` returns the `lineno` and file path of the call
    caller = get_caller() # Unsure of how to implement
    arg_key = get_arg_key() # Unsure of how to implement
    return fetch_configured_value(caller, arg_key) # Fetch default arg from global config
```

Before posting on SO, I tried to use `inspect.stack`. The caller (e.g. `some_function`) does not appear in the stack of `configurable_arg`. However, `inspect.stack` has the `lineno` the default arg was declared. This experience inspired the current question.

Comment: Added the use case to the question via edit.

Comment: I feel like your usecase either confuses the issue or points out an xy problem. How does line number figure there at all? Why does normal inspection of the module's contents not yield the result you want? Default arguments are not especially difficult to retrieve.

Comment: (1) Added it at the end, `inspect.stack` provides the `lineno` as well as the file path that the default argument was declared. This inspired by the current question. (2) Inspecting the caller function returns `<module>` and not the function in question.

Comment: This is not describing the use-case at all. Are you trying to dynamically generate argument defaults? If so, based upon what info?

Comment: Edited to be more concrete. The argument defaults are dynamically set by a configuration file created by the user. This is possible with a decorator. However, I'd like to experiment with the above strategy, also.

Comment: So, regarding the question title - what does the line number have to do with it?  And what does importing the function have to do with it?

Comment: Being able to import the function given the line number would solve this use case, mostly. Initially, I just posted the question for clarity but have been asked to describe the use case in the comments.

Comment: Whilst this is possible in Python, it seems like a really convoluted implementation and there is almost certainly a more sensible approach. What is the format of this "configuration file created by the user"?  How are you supposing using the line number or being able to import the function help you in this regard?

Comment: The configuration file consists of function paths with their arguments declared. Being able to import the function will allow me to get the function name and its module path.

Comment: That's a fool's errand, because the function must be well-defined in order to import it, and you want to customize the definition of the function at import time (which is when the default arguments are bound). Can you see how this is a chicken-and-egg situation?

Comment: The configuration is setup before import time, so it's fine. I have already got the same specs working with a decorator, I'm exploring a more syntactically pleasing approach.

Comment: You're missing the point. The function object *isn't defined* until `configured_arg()` returns a value, which is then bound as the default in the function signature. So you can't, from within `configured_arg` call, import the original function - because it isn't fully existing yet!  That would be a circular import.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense, you are right. However, we do not need to import the function, we just need the function import path/function name to fetch its configuration.

Comment: Now we are on the same page.  So you can edit the question, which still says "How do you import a Python 3 function ...".  Let's get to the actual requirement (dynamically provide function argument defaults from config files) rather than asking about the attempted solution (importing a function from the module name and line number)

Comment: @MichaelPetrochuk [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), this way is with a decorator. I don't know what led you to think that the decorator approach was not convenient, but let me propose a solution (see my answer) which cleanly does what you need without even having to use `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the function `configured_args` is called, the function for which it sets default arguments is not yet defined.

You need to change the default arguments *after* the function definition. One way to do that is to use a decorator.

You can then use the following attributes of a function to find its location across your modules.

- `__module__`: the name of the module where the function is defined;
- `__name__`: the name of the function;
- [`__qualname__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/): the full path of the function in the module. By example a function `f` defined inside a class `A` will have `__qualname__` set to `A.f`.

### Code

```
from functools import wraps

def get_kwargs(qualname, module):
    # Get the default kwargs from configs
    return {'kwarg': ...}

def configure_args(f):
    qualname = f.__qualname__
    module = f.__module__

    default_kwargs = get_kwargs(qualname, module)

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        new_kwargs = {**default_kwargs , **kwargs}
        return f(*args, **new_kwargs)

    return wrapper

@configure_args
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

The function `my_func` now has a default keyword argument `kwarg`.